# Filter function overwrites formula with '--'

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the filter formula below. The formula works fine the first time, but once it filters the result properly, it corrupts the same formula in next row below with `--`.

```
=iferror(FILTER(PROVEEDORES!C:C,PROVEEDORES!B:B=C252),"--- No Existe ---")
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens is you delete the `--`? When you look what's in the cell, you'll find out it says something like this: `=CONTINUE(C2, 2, 1)

Comment: **correct** @jacob

Comment: What is correct about my statement?

Comment: What do you mean regarding  "the formula works fine the first time"? Are you filling down several cells with the same formula?

Answer (score 1):

What happens is you delete the `--`? When you look what's in the cell, you'll find out it says something like this: `=CONTINUE(C2, 2, 1)`.

This is a clear indication that the current result has lesser values than the previous result.

Comment: Thanks, but all filter reference is unique. @jacob

Comment: I replied correct to your comment that I get in the row below of correct formula I get the statement =CONTINUE(C2,2,1) @jacab

Comment: The CONTINUE() function was removed from Google Sheets.